# Running Linux Command from PHP

Tags: php, linux, permissions, exec, shell-exec

I have a bit of a unique situation. I'm trying to run a video encoding program from a PHP script called Diascope, which relies on the 'convert' command provided by ImageMagick. I have a bash script that executes a really simple conversion and then it runs the application called Diascope. This is the conversion code, and the following does work, it creates the new file

```
convert image.jpg image.png
```

Shows no errors, but then I run Diascope like this

```
diascope -clean audio.txt
```

And I can see that Diascope loads property because it prints "Diascope 0.2.1":

> diascope 0.2.1 (ms 2006-2010) slideshow generator See
>   http://diascope.sf.net for documentation and updates.
>
> Error: executable program not found: convert Please see the
>   requirements for diascope in the release notes.

When I run `shell_exec("whoami");` it prints "nobody"

So why can I run convert by itself, but the "diascope" process can't seem to utilize it? I have tried going into `/usr/local/bin/convert` and chmoding it to 777, but it didn't seem to have any effect, what else could I try here?

UPDATE: I should probably add that when I try to run `diascope -clean audio.txt` as root on the terminal, it creates the audio.flv file like it should, also I can't seem to `sudo su nobody` it returns `This account is currently not available.`

Comment: Thank you for not signing posts.

Comment: Oh jesus christ you've done it on almost 200

Comment: Sorry? Do you mean the "Thanks for reading" note? I can stop doing that, lol

Comment: No, I meant, "lol I edited out your redundant 'thanks' message, and here's my ironic comment asking you in a backwards lollish way not to do it again" _[edit: well, yea, basically ;)]_

Comment: what distribution do you use? Check your syslog/logs and see if something shows up when you run the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP runs as the same user as apache, which is typically www-data or nobody. I believe you can use suPHP+apache to change the user that PHP runs under.