# Run a linux command php when a button is pressed

Tags: php, ajax, linux, shell-exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Linux Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707040/running-linux-command-from-php)

I have script which combines some audio files depending upon the users selection. When the user click on a button, I want a script to execute in linux and play the resulting file, that is generated.

What is the way to run a linux command when a button is pressed in PHP?

Comment: exec(). but im not sure that's what you really want. did you expect linux to play the file?

Comment: couple more dupes in the *Related Section*. Please search before asking. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for a way to call the shellexec using ajax or something else when the button is clicked